# getSymbols always throws errors. What am I missing?

Tags: r

Just copying a simple code. But getSymbols always throws errors:

```
# Set initial values
initDate='2002-07-31'
endDate='2012-10-31'
initEq=100000

start<-"2005-01-01"
end<- format(Sys.Date(),"%Y-%m-%d") # yyyy-mm-dd 

# Set currency and instruments
currency("USD")
stock("IEF",currency="USD",multiplier=1)
stock("SPY",currency="USD",multiplier=1)

# Load data with quantmod
print("Loading data")
symbols = c("IEF", "SPY")
getSymbols(symbols, from=start, to=end)
```

Errors:

> Warning messages:
>       1: In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
>         downloaded length 108057 != reported length 200
>       2: In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
>         downloaded length 120958 != reported length 200

Why?

Comment: Those are not errors but warning messages. They are thrown by `download.file` statement.

Comment: ah ok and what do they mean? I mean I cannot influence the getSymbols function.

Comment: They mean exactly what they say: the remote filesystem reports a file of length 200 but a much bigger file than that was actually downloaded.  You need to look at what you've got to see what happened.

Comment: hm well I think the downloaded file is large enough with 13152 entries. However neither number matches this 13152 that's why I'm confused...